# Creating a Vector Tile base map

Tags: rendering, basemap, vector-tiles

I want to create a vector tile base map using my own shapefiles/postgis tables for use on a mobile primarily. By my understanding the process is divided into 3 main steps:

1. Creating/slicing the data into vector tiles.
2. Using a server to host the tiles.
3. Rendering the tiles.

I have looked into various methods to do this, The [Mapzen Vector Tiles](https://github.com/mapzen/vector-datasource) were the first thing I looked into. They come with a very good rendering option as well. I got it to work with osm data but I wasn't able to configure it to work with my own PostGIS Tables. The processing and queries assume that the data is from osm.

Currently I am looking into [PGRestAPI](https://github.com/spatialdev/PGRestAPI), I have been able to create my tiles and host them pretty easily but I am not sure how I will render them on the mobile. I am not able to parse the vector tile endpoints that I get from the server. The Leaflet Vector-Tile plugin is also something I have looked into but I'm not sure how to go about using it on mobile.

How do I go about rendering the vector tiles on a mobile? And is there any alternative way to go about creating a vector tile base map for use on a mobile?

Comment: I believe Mapbox has a mobile / native mapbox GL framework that works with MVTs?

Answer (score 1):

If ArcGIS pro is an option here I would reccomend it.

**My personal tips:**

- follow rules mentioned in below links (bottom two are tutorial which may be useful)
- add map descritpion in map properties
- uncheck *Package for ArcGIS online [...]*
- when you add map ArcGIS Pro will load tiling scheme, click on its name and you will see path, copy it and paste to for ex. Google Chrome --> then pick suitable scale for you, remove coma and place delimeter as seen below (**don't shrink number**)
- when I was making Vector Tile Package, premade Indexed Polygons caused some bugs, so I won't recomned using it (it doesn't take off a lot of time from whole process)
- Use Create Mobile Map Package to use it on mobile (output format is mmpk)

[image]

**Link to the Esri documentation**

http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/create-vector-tile-package.htm

**Tips on creating Vector Tiles Map**

http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/mapping/map-authoring/author-a-map-for-vector-tile-creation.htm

**Multiscaled map tips**

http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/mapping/map-authoring/author-a-multiscaled-map.htm

**Creating Vector Tiles - video from Esri User Conference 2016**

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L2ds2rb-d5c

**Creating Mobile Map Package**

http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/create-mobile-map-package.htm

**Tutorial part 1**

https://community.esri.com/community/gis/applications/arcgis-pro/blog/2018/01/20/use-arcgis-pro-21-to-make-an-offline-map

**Tutorial part 2**

https://community.esri.com/community/gis/applications/arcgis-pro/blog/2018/01/20/use-arcgis-pro-21-to-make-an-offline-map-part-2

Answer (score 1):

[Geoserver](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/extensions/vectortiles/tutorial.html) can publish data in vector tile specification. It supports theree type of format,

MapBox Vector (MVT) = Recommended Format This is an efficient binary format that is widely supported by almost all Vector Tile applications.
GeoJson =   This is a human readable JSON format. Although many geo-spatial applications support GeoJSON datasets, few Vector Tile applications support tiles in this format. Supported by Open Layers 3.
TopoJson = This is a very complex, but somewhat human readable JSON format that is good for polygon coverages. It is not a widely supported and very few Vector Tile applications support it. Suported by Open Layers 3.

Source: [Geoserver](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/extensions/vectortiles/tutorial.html)

Answer (score -1):

[Clockwork Micro](https://clockworkmicro.com/) offers services to either tile and host shapefiles or draw vector tiles directly from postgis. You can add basic styling and combine layers in a map with its own url. (I am part of Clockwork Micro, but have posted because our service knits together OS tools to do exactly what's asked about here.)